# How to build the jar for the project having only test classes using maven build

Tags: java, maven

My Project is having only test classes inside src/test/java (No src/main/java folder). I want to build the project using maven and create the jar -1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file including all the classes.
I am using the following pom.xml

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>jarName</finalName><!-- Name of the resulting JAR file -->
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <mainClass>ClassNameWithPackageStructure</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>GroupPackage</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxxxxxxxx</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>integration-tests</artifactId>

    <properties>
        ........
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ..........
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am using maven package command and the build is success, but inside target folder, two jars (***jarName-tests.jar*** and ***jarName-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.jar***) are generated with warning ***JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!***. When I checked the jars, ***jarName-tests.jar*** has the compiled classes inside and ***jarName-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.jar*** not having the compiled classes. But my goal is to generate the ***jarName-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.jar*** including all the classes.

Please correct me what I am doing wrong to get the proper jar.

Comment: I found some documentation by Maven: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

Comment: What is this for? Tests in `src/test/java` are meant to be run during the build. There is no need to package them into a JAR.

Comment: This is some specific requirement to create the jar and run in on some different environment, because in that particular environment we can't build and bundle the jars.. so our aim is to create this jar as a executable one..

Comment: Do you want to create a test jar for some testing purposes?

Comment: Yes Maksim.. As said already this jar will be running in some different env.. Creating jars in diff env, push it another and run there..

Answer (score 0):

See [skipIfEmpty](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#skipIfEmpty) configuration for the `maven-jar-plugin`.

You need something like:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>test-jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And you should stick to the default jar naming (remove the `finalName` from the configuration shown in your question) - messing with the jar names can have unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by creating an assembly.xml and adding maven-assembly-plugin in the pom.xml. Now the jar is created with all the test classes along with the dependency classes too.

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>mainclassName</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```